# Is fight during launch from Mars depicted properly in Ad Astra?

Tags: ad-astra

In the movie Ad Astra there was fight in the rocket. When rockets stage detached one of the people smashed against the door. But most of the time it was look like they're in space already (no gravity), as if it would not in accelerating rocket, but it should.

Comment: I can't remember the details of the scene - probably somewhat due to the fact it was the worst movie I've seen in years.  Can you remind me a little more, how are you sure its not accelerating at the time?  They have to reach the outer solar system, so even if acceleration is low, they do need to accelerate right?  Just because you can't see a visible flame doesn't mean the rocket isn't working.

Comment: @iandotkelly (you understood me the opposite way) I mean it looked like as it wasn't accelerating, thought it had to because they were flying from Mars surface to the orbit at the moment and because of acceleration I think they couldn't move as they did during the fight, it looked like they're in space already. Why the worst, to me it was awesome, very interesting movie. (couldn't find on the Internet clip of those scene yet)

Comment: Its ponderous and flat, and I couldn't have cared less about the character and his daddy issues. It relies far too much on voiceover.  It tries to look 'realistic' like this is the near future, but the science is poorly represented.  The moon surface trip and subsequent pirate attack is completely unexplained, and uses Apollo era equipment for no good reason - its thrown in for some cool action but doesn't make any sense.  I love science fiction, I love slow moody movies, I like Brad Pitt as an actor.  This movie should have been perfect for me - I almost walked out it was so terrible.

Comment: This review fairly sums it up for me https://www.thespacereview.com/article/3805/1

Comment: @iandotkelly - I might have to watch this again, just to see how bad. My database says I've seen it, but I either fell asleep or otherwise just completely forgot I've ever watched it...

Answer (score 2):

> as if it would not in accelerating rocket, but it should.

> I mean it looked like as it wasn't accelerating, thought it had to because they were flying from Mars surface to the orbit at the moment

Your comment does not prove that they were under **constant** acceleration. There is no need to keep accelerating. In space, your orbital movement is not just decided by the amount of acceleration, but also the location (in your orbit) that you are in while accelerating.

Once a sufficient suborbital trajectory is achieved, it's more efficient to coast (i.e. engines off) until you're at the apoaps (highest point), only to *then* accelerate up to orbital (and then escape) velocity.
Nowadays, constant burns are sometimes done because of engineering constraints, but in a Mars-inhabiting civilization you can assume there's been technological advancements since then.

I don't know the flight specifics, and I suspect neither do you. But the basis of your assumption that it "had to" be accelerating is not provably correct.

> But most of the time it was look like they're in space already (no gravity)

Pedantry: there's still gravity, but any orbiting (or even suborbital) body not under acceleration is in free fall, which looks the same as being in zero gravity.

If I put you in a box and let that box fall straight down, you are "floating" in the box as if you're in space. In reality, you and the box are hurtling towards the Earth's surface, but you can "float" around the box because you are in free fall.

Therefore, it "looking like space" (as per your quote) actually proves that they are not under any acceleration (which supports my earlier point). What it *doesn't* prove is *where* they are (i.e. atmosphere, lower orbit, upper orbit, deep space).

> When rockets stage detached one of the people smashed against the door.

Detachment uses small explosions to decouple the stages. It's perfectly possible that this decoupling jolts the craft enough to very briefly accelerate it - though I wouldn't put it past the movie makers to exaggerate this effect.